# Is there an example of a group G and an infinite subset H of G that is not a subgroup of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there an example of a group G and an infinite subset H of G that is closed under the group operation  but is not a subgroup of G?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb Z$ with addition and the subset $\{0,1,2,3\dots \}$

Comment: Trivial examples are the worst :-)

Comment: I guess, although any such example must be rather similar to this one. Specifically, you need the set to contain an element $g$ of infinite order, along with all its positive powers, but without its inverses.

Comment: I meant "worst" only as in "annoyingly simple one shoulda thought of it"

Comment: A variant, showing that it's possible with even less structure: $\{6, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28\} \cup \{30,31,32,33,\dots\}$.

Comment: Any example of such a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set obtained as sum of numbers in a set $S$. In this answer, a minimal $S$ is $\{0,1\}$, and in @GregMartin's example, a minimal $S$ is $\{6, 10, 15\}$.

Comment: @JiK as written your assertion is a bit void as you can take every example set itself as set $S$. Maybe you meant to say that the set $S$ can be chosen to be finite.

Comment: @quid I did give examples of minimal sets $S$ in those two cases, so I don't see your point.

Comment: @JiK "Any example of such a subset of Z is the set obtained as sum of numbers in a set S." Is trivial.

Comment: @quid Yes, I could as well have written "The set in this answer is obtained as a sum of numbers in the set $\{0,1\}$ which is also minimal set with that property. Also, in the other example such a set would be $\{6,10,15\}$ which is also minimal." But for some reason I thought the version I ended up with has more readable sentence structure.

Comment: @JiK Alright. I just thought you had maybe missed a word. I do think that your observation adds something. One might elaborate on it by saying that an example is obtained by a choosing a finite set of numbers of the same sign and considering the semigroup generated by it, and these are all examples.

Comment: Inside $\Bbb Z$, both the fact that all elements must be the same sign (other than perhaps $0$) and the fact that a finite generating set exists are interesting exercises.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. A subgroup must be closed under the operation and have inverses. Any subset that doesn't have inverses cannot be a subgroup. (Note that in a finite group, closed is enough as elements will form finite cycles.)

Another example besides the simple one Jorge gave is the $\Bbb Q \cap (1,\infty)$ with multiplication.